# Applying validation in angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a set of reusable components in `AngularJS 1.5.x version`. Each directive accepts a model like below.

```
<app-grid ng-model="scope.gridModel" />
```

The gridModel is a simple class looks like below,

```
function GridModel(cols) {
   this.cols = cols;
}
```

Is there any way I can check in the directive that the passed model is of type `GridModel` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this, in my directive `link` function:

```
...
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
  if (ngModel instanceof GridModel) {
    // right class
  } else {
    // wrong class
  }
},
...
```

**UPDATE**:
This will check the `ngModel` instance type instantly.
If you want to check the type in the event it changes, you should set up a `$watch`...
Something like this:

```
scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue instanceof GridModel) {
    // right class
  } else {
    // wrong class
  }
});
```

Comment: This will work only for the first time rgt? What happens if the model changes later. Let's say somewhere sometime the model is set to a different type.

Comment: That's cool. I'm little new to angular and so one more question. The scope.$watch will do a deep watch rgt? If so the case how I can make the watch more flat here?

Comment: You can control the depth of a `$watch` with the 3rd parameter:

Comment: `scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ }, true);` is deep, while `scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ }, false);` is not...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. First, I suggest you create a service to access the `GridModel` object, so that you can access the object from the controller and from the directive.

```
myApp.service('GridService', function() {
    this.GridModel = function(cols) {
        this.cols = cols;
    };
});
```

Then, in your directive, you can check if the model is of type `GridModel` using `InstanceOf`.

```
var GridModel = GridService.GridModel;
$scope.isGridModel = ($scope.model instanceof GridModel);
```

I built an example with a directive that will show `true` if its model is of type `GridModel`, otherwise `false`. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5odst8pb/2/) for the example.